# Why These 2 functions got so much performance difference? and what i change is value declariation place

Tags: javascript

```
function check(num){
    let stringtoLoop = num;
    let overAll = 0;
    while(stringtoLoop.length > 1){
    for(let i = 0; i < stringtoLoop.length; i++){
        overAll += Number(stringtoLoop[i]);
    }
    stringtoLoop = overAll.toString();
    }
    return stringtoLoop;
  }
  console.log(check('1234567'));
```

In the above code OverAll is declared outside the while loop. This program may slow down the browser when i check big number.

```
function check(num){
    let stringtoLoop = num;
    while(stringtoLoop.length > 1){
    let overAll = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < stringtoLoop.length; i++){
        overAll += Number(stringtoLoop[i]);
    }
    stringtoLoop = overAll.toString();
    }
    return stringtoLoop;
  }
  console.log(check('1234567'));
```

Here is another code and in here Overall is declared inside the while loop. This program got no problem checking big number. This program run smoothly

What I want to know is why These 2 programs behave so differently?

Comment: while loop is unnecessary anyway...

Comment: Well if you tried to run them, you should notice that they don't do the same thing?

Comment: Put a `console.log(overAll, stringtoLoop)` before the `stringtoLoop = overAll.toString();` line and you should see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

When overAll is declared outside of the while loop, the value is incremented on each iteration. When it's inside the while loop, it is recreated with an initial value of 0. Looking at the first function, when the while loop runs for the first time, let's use check('1234'), the value of overAll is incremented by the for loop to 10. stringtoLoop becomes '10'. Since the length of stringtoLoop > 1, it performs another iteration which further increments the value of overAll. The while loop with therefore continue to iterate until the you run out of memory. Contract with with the second example, where overAll is 0 for each iteration of the while loop. The first iteration yields 10, so it goes into the second iteration, however this time overAll would be 1 i.e. 0 + 1 + 1. The while loop would be terminated because stringtoLoop.length = 1.

Comment: summarized: The first version of `check` creates an endless loop when the digits of `num` add up to a value with more than two digits (10 or larger).

Comment: Yip, that sums it up.